# How to avoid a new line with the 'p' tag

Tags: html, css, tags

How can I stay on the same line while working with the `<p>` tag?

I want to create a carousel with an image and text.

Comment: @Nishant: When you have to *force* a tag to behave a certain way (such as making it `display: inline;` rather than `display: block;`), it's a good indication that you might be using the wrong tag...

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Use the `display: inline` CSS property.

Ideal: In the stylesheet:

```
#container p { display: inline }
```

Bad/Extreme situation: Inline:

```
<p style="display:inline">...</p>
```

Comment: Span is the same and doesn't go onto a new line! as `one.beat.consumer` said

Comment: +1 Useful for saving space on mobile devices using responsive media queries :D

Comment: I'm working in angularJS, and I needed to repeat a paragraph with 'ng-repeat', this worked perfectly. And Span only gave me error.

Comment: One would need this when dealing with a program who's output uses <p> tags as separators. Django forms for example.

Answer (score 103):

The `<p>` paragraph tag is meant for specifying paragraphs of text. If you don't want the text to start on a new line, I would suggest you're using the `<p>` tag incorrectly. Perhaps the `<span>` tag more closely fits what you want to achieve...?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No direct answer to the question, but probably the better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 33):

I came across this for CSS,

```css
span, p{overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;}
```

via [a similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232310/htmlcss-how-to-force-div-contents-to-stay-in-one-line).

Comment: I didn't need the overflow:hidden. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Something like

```css
p
{
    display: inline;
}
```

in your stylesheet would do it for all *p* tags.

Answer (score 3):

[Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) works.

```css
.box{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #e3f2fd;
}
.item{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ffebee;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="item">A</p>
  <p class="item">B</p>
  <p class="item">C</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with [the currently accepted answer](/a/2076111) and other examples as they will lead to bad practices. The accepted answer is not w3c spec. The `p` tag is a [display block element](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-p-tag.html) and should be used as a container for [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2).

If you don't want a paragraph and you need elements inline, then don't use the `p` tag. Use span or another [option for the inline content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content).