# How can I force div contents to stay in one line with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

[I have a long text inside a `div` with defined `width`](http://jsfiddle.net/NXchy/):

HTML:

```html
<div>Stack Overflow is the BEST!!!</div>
```

CSS:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70px;
}
```

How could I force the string to stay in one line (i.e., to be cut in the middle of "Overflow")?

I tried to use `overflow: hidden`, but it didn't help.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` put this in your style tag.

Answer (score 673, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 106):

Use `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:hidden`

http://jsfiddle.net/NXchy/8/

Comment: Add ```text-overflow:ellipsis;``` to above for better look.

Comment: can this be achieved with no css?

Answer (score 73):

In your CSS section, use `white-space: nowrap;`.

Answer (score 28):

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>Stack Overflow is the BEST!!!</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

I made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/kh4aR/

RobAgar pointed out `white-space:nowrap`.

A couple of things here: You need `overflow: hidden` if you don't want to see the extra characters poking out into your layout.

Also, as mentioned, you could use `white-space: pre` (see EnderMB), keeping in mind that `pre` will not collapse white space whereas `white-space: nowrap` will.

Answer (score 12):

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

was the solution that worked for me. In some cases with `div`-lists, this is needed.

Some alternative direction values are `row-reverse`, `column`, `column-reverse`, `unset`, `initial`, and `inherit`. Which do the things you expect them to do.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your div:

```css
white-space: nowrap;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NXchy/1/

Comment: you can add: overflow: auto to display a horizontal scrollbar

Answer (score 5):

in span you need to add :
`{ display: block; }`

```css
span {
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

```html
<span>Stack Overflow is the BEST!!!</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try. It uses `pre` rather than `nowrap` as I would assume you would want this to run similarly to `<pre>`, but either will work just fine:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 70px;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NXchy/11/

Answer (score 4):

None of the previous answers worked for me.

There are instances where regardless what you do, and depending on the system (Oracle Designer: Oracle 11g - PL/SQL), *divs* will always go to the next line, in which case you should use the *span* tag instead.

This worked wonders for me.

```html
<span float: left; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; onmouseover="rollOverImageSectionFiveThreeOne(this)">
    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="p_verify_type" value="SomeValue"  />
</span> 
Just Your Text || 
<span id="headerFiveThreeOneHelpText" float: left; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;></span>
```

Comment: Huge help on this, this was all that worked for me, probably spent 30 minutes on this, lol. Oddly, I'm not using any of what you mentioned, css, javascript, bootstrap, and some custom css.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a height, so the block cannot grow to accommodate your text, and keep the `overflow: hidden` parameter.

Here is an example of what you might like if you need to display two lines high:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70px;
    height: 2.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: In your case the nowrap option is probably better, but I left my answer because I sometimes find myself needing a block that may have some lines wrapping until it overflows like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NXchy/7/ (changed the link from Stephenmurdoch's version, thanks!)

Comment: No need for this, what happens if the user wants to bump up the text size using ctrl-+? Keeping the height flexible is better.

Comment: If the user resizes the text with ctrl-+ is should just work: http://jsfiddle.net/kpKW3/

Comment: Using `em`'s in the `height` keeps it flexible, key point well illustrated here in your example.