# Using Css to prevent wrapping of text with previous text?

Tags: css

Is there a CSS way to prevent a text element from wrapping from a previous text element?

i.e.
`My Table Header <i class="fa fa-search"></i>` shows as

> My
>
> Table
>
> Header
>
> MySearchIcon

But I want it to display like this:

> My
>
> Table
>
> Header MySearchIcon

The actual code is a combination of Razor and Html

```
  <th>
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Projects.FirstOrDefault().Name) <i class="fa fa-search smaller fa-fade"></i>
  </th>
```

This is in a header of a table and depending on the header length I do want wrapping but I want a space and the icon to be stuck to the last word in the header and not wrap.

Because of the Razor piece of the code I can't place the non-breaking space up against the output directly,

Comment: Why are the words wrapping in the first place? I mean, obviously the system thinks that the text "My Table" is to long to fit on a line, so the text "Header MySearchIcon" would definitely be.

Comment: can you add a <br> tag after "table", If so hide the <br> tag and display it back when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use white-space:nowrap; in your css.

You can also examine this question:
[HTML+CSS: How to force div contents to stay in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232310/htmlcss-how-to-force-div-contents-to-stay-in-one-line)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You can use an HTML entity for a nonbreaking space.  It would make your text node and icon be as follows

`My Table Header&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-search"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being to add a  element after the razor code.
i.e.

```
 <th>
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Projects.FirstOrDefault().Name)<text>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-search smaller fa-fade"></i></text>
  </th>
```