# Aligning 3 section tags in a row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

I am having 3 `section` tags in a row but on giving a margin, the last section tag slides to the next line instead of remaining in a single line. 
I have tried using `float:left` and `display:inline` property but its not working.

Here is my code:

```css
#main-content h2 {
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#main-content section {
  background-color: #6c757d;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 33%;
}

#main-content h3 {
  color: #000;
}

#main-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="text-center">Our Menu</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 ">
      <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
      <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
        laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
        vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis magna
        a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
      <h3 class="text-center">Beef</h3>
      <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
        laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
        vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis magna
        a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <h3 class="text-center">Sushi</h3>
      <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
        laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
        vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis magna
        a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232310/htmlcss-how-to-force-div-contents-to-stay-in-one-line Use white-space:nowrap, overflow: hidden.

Comment: @mentallurg Using white-space:nowrap, overflow: hidden cuts down the text in every section and still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: You wanted to get it in a single row? You got it. Now you want to make your element higher? This is another question :) Specify the height explicitly in your CSS. Currently it is missing.

Comment: @mentallurg the sections don't come in a single row even after using white-space:nowrap and overflow: hidden property

Comment: Why do you add the margin? Also overriding the `width` to `33%` will break all the responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Can not use `margin-left` and `margin-right` for columns that are inside `row`.
- Can not use `width` for the columns because `col-*` has already width.

  I understand why you do so. To achieve what you want,  use a a new `container` element for the content of the section, and use `background` for it.

```css
.bg-gray {
  background-color: #6c757d;
}

.border-1px-dark {
    border: 1px solid;
}

#main-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="text-center mt-2 mb-5">Our Menu</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 ">
      <div class="bg-gray border-1px-dark p-3">
        <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
        <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
          laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
          vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis
          magna a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
      <div class="bg-gray border-1px-dark p-3">
        <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
        <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
          laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
          vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis
          magna a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <div class="bg-gray border-1px-dark p-3">
        <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
        <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
          laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
          vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis
          magna a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Style such as `color:000;` is useless to use because, by default, font color is `black`. Only use if you want your text have a color other than `black`.

---

If you want to have some space between columns on mobiles only, use `pb-* pb-sm-0` for the sections.

```css
.bg-gray {
  background-color: #6c757d;
}

.border-1px-dark {
    border: 1px solid;
}

#main-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="text-center mt-2 mb-5">Our Menu</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 pb-4 pb-sm-0">
      <div class="bg-gray border-1px-dark p-3">
        <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
        <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
          laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
          vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis
          magna a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 pb-4 pb-sm-0">
      <div class="bg-gray border-1px-dark p-3">
        <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
        <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
          laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
          vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis
          magna a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 pb-4 pb-sm-0">
      <div class="bg-gray border-1px-dark p-3">
        <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
        <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
          laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
          vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis
          magna a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have all your styles. If they are not in conflict, following works.

```
<html>
<style>
#main-content h2 {
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#main-content section {
  background-color: #6c757d;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  width: 32%;
  display:inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#main-content h3 {
  color: #000;
}

#main-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="text-center">Our Menu</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 ">
      <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
      <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
        laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
        vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis magna
        a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
      <h3 class="text-center">Beef</h3>
      <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
        laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
        vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis magna
        a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <h3 class="text-center">Sushi</h3>
      <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur
        laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui,
        vehicula vehicula dui porta sed. Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis magna
        a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Attention: margin-left: 5px is in conflict with width: 33%. If you have the window width 900px, then 3 sections will take 99% = 891px. 3 margins will take totally 3 x 5px = 15px. The total width will be 891 + 15 = 906px > 900px. So your last section will be moved to the next row. To avoid this, you can use margin in percent, like margin-left: 0.5%

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended using div tags for bootstrap styling.hardcoding the styles in CSS can affect the responsiveness of the site.You can place col classes in the div outside section tag.

Take a look at this codepen  [Align sections using bootstrap](https://codepen.io/ankesh/pen/ZRbmBM)

```
<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
<h2 class="text-center">Our Menu</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 ">
        <section>
            <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
            <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis
                egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem
                velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis
                tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend
                arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui, vehicula vehicula dui porta sed.
                Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur
                sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis magna
                a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum
                nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 ">
        <section>
            <h3 class="text-center">Beef</h3>
            <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis
                egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem
                velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis
                tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend
                arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui, vehicula vehicula dui porta sed.
                Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur
                sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis magna
                a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum
                nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 ">
        <section>
            <h3 class="text-center">Sushi</h3>
            <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie ex odio, eu lobortis libero mollis
                egestas. Duis porta orci a semper varius. Donec vulputate tellus a neque auctor ultricies. Vivamus sem
                velit, dictum eu erat vel, consectetur laoreet leo. Fusce vitae tortor dolor. Duis semper, leo non sagittis
                tristique, metus nibh vehicula velit, et maximus ligula ligula id diam. Sed est libero, venenatis eleifend
                arcu quis, imperdiet porta velit. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui, vehicula vehicula dui porta sed.
                Pellentesque ornare nulla tellus, eget gravida magna placerat vel. Ut mollis placerat turpis, eget consectetur
                sapien porttitor ac. Aenean posuere cursus nibh eu vulputate. Ut sit amet orci posuere, venenatis magna
                a, molestie nibh. Pellentesque id orci porttitor, varius justo sed, luctus eros. Vivamus eu elementum
                nisl. Maecenas nec lobortis mi. Fusce nec tortor sed sapien fringilla imperdiet nec sed arcu.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```