# How to avoid going to new line with p tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My desired Output is:-

```
Date: "current date"
```

My current code for this is:-

```
<p align="right">Date: </p>
    <p id="demo" align="right">
    <script>
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toDateString();
    </script>
</p>
```

which is giving me the output as:

```
Date:
"current date"
```

So how can I avoid new line so that I can get both the element on same line?

Comment: You might prefer to simply use other markup than P. P stands for paragraph. Paragraphs usually have more than 2-3 words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to avoid a new line with p tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076109/how-to-avoid-a-new-line-with-p-tag)

Answer (score 10):

You can change your markup but I assume that you have no control over your HTML, so, `p` is a *block level element* by default, hence you need to use `display: inline-block;` or `display: inline;`

```
p {
    display: inline; /* Better use inline-block if you want the p 
                        tag to be inline as well as persist the block 
                        state */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kcL75/1/)

Just a heads up for you, take out you `script` tag out of the `p` element. Also note that you are using attribute to align your text, where you can do that with CSS like `text-align: right;` instead of <s>`align="right"`</s>

Comment: where should I use it?

Comment: for the p that you dont want to get a new line just use <p align="right" style="display:inline-block">Date: </p>  or if you want to make it easy for you use a class for that p  like this <p align="right" class="pWithoutLineBreak">Date: </p>  and in your <style>.pWithoutLineBreak{display:inline-block;}</style>

Answer (score 4):

You're getting a lint break because there are two p's. Try this:

```
<p align="right" id="demo">Date: 
    <script>
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toDateString();
    </script>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You also shouldn't put script inside paragraph element. I suggest you re-formatting your code like this:

```
<p>Date: <span id="date"></span></p>
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = d.toDateString();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p align="right" id= "demo"> Date: </p>
<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toDateString();
</script>
```

This should work. You were attaching the innerHTML to the nested p tag and hence you were getting a line break. And because of its block behaviour it was coming to the next line. Attach the innerHTML to the 1st p tag itself